# Proof of the Theorem of Grothendieck

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-explanation

My question refers to a step in the proof of THM 2.1.1 (Grotherdieck) from excerpt from "Vector Bundles on Complex Projective Spaces" by Christian Okonek, Michael Schneider, Heinz Spindler (page 12):

Consider a non trivial section $s \in H^0(\mathbb{P}^1, E(k_0)$ such that $s(x)=0$ for a point $x \in \mathbb{P}^1$.

Equivalently: $s(x) =0 \in E(k_0)_{\mathbb{P}^1,x}/m_x$ or $s(x) \in m_x$ in the unique max ideal of the stalk $E(k_0)_{\mathbb{P}^1,x}$.

I have two questions:

1.: Why does it imply that $s$ in a section of the tensor sheaf $E(k_0) \otimes_{\mathbb{P}^1} J_x$ where $J_x$ is the corresponding ideal sheaf of the point $x$ interpreted as closed subscheme of $\mathbb{P}^1$.

2. Why $J_x = \mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{\mathbb{P}^1}}(-1)$ as sheaf?

I know that $J_x$ naturally belongs to exact sequence

$$0 \to J_x \to \mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{\mathbb{P}^1}} \to \mathcal{O}_x \to 0$$

where $\mathcal{O}_x$ is skyscraper with only non trivial stalk $k(x)$ in $x$.

But why $J_x = \mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{\mathbb{P}^1}}(-1)$?

Comment: *HINT*: A point in $\Bbb P^1$ is a "hyperplane section."

Comment: Perhaps I'm just rusty, but can you please explain the notation $E(k_0)$.

Comment: Oh sorry, that just means $E \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(k_o)$

Comment: @Ted Shifrin: Would you like to explain this a bit more, please? I'm not familar with the approach by (topological) vector bundles, only algebraic vb (= locally free sheafs). By GAGA that' quite the same, but I don't see how the hyperplane section argument works.

Comment: @KarlPeter The ideal sheaf of a degree $d$ hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^n$ is $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(-d)$.